# Is there any injective ring homomorphism from the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2 −y^2 )$ into the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x, y]/(x − y^2 )$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

There exists an injective ring homomorphism from the ring
$\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2 −y^2)$ into the
ring $\mathbb{Q}[x, y]/(x − y^2)$

I think the statement is false because the number of generators of the first ring is greater in some sense. Can anybody please help?

Comment: What is $Q$? Is it $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: I have edited it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such injection: The ring $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x-y^2)\cong \mathbb{Q}[y]$ is an integral domain, hence so is every subring. But $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2-y^2)$ has zero-divisors, because $(x-y)(x+y) = x^2-y^2$ (and neither of the factors becomes zero in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2-y^2)$).